# MSTest. Is it possible that it would keep count of ignored tests?

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

I would like to generate statistics from the test run, and would like to keep track of these 4 numbers: 
failed / passed / inconclusive and ignored tests.

My question is... is it possible to get the number of skipped/ignored tests (this is a test method attributed with [Ignore]).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any working solutions for this yet.

Please see this issue in Microsoft tracker: [mstest.exe report file (trx) does not list ignored tests](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779743/mstest-exe-report-file-trx-does-not-list-ignored-tests). The status for it is "Closed as Deferred".

However, the current design seems to make more sense to me. Statistics for **test runs** should only include the tests that are supposed to be executed. Tests marked with `[Ignore]` should not be considered as a part of test run. If people have excluded some tests from test runs **intentionally**, then why would they want to see them in the test run results?

But I'd like to see this feature personally. More statistics won't hurt after all.